# real time graph interval window

Tags: highcharts

I have a real time line graph with new data points adding to the series as time passes by.I want to limit this to one hour window and shift plot to the left.At any time plot shoud show data points of one hour and navigator handle max interval should be one hour as well.How to achive this?

Comment: Do you want that points should be added only for 1 hour ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `afterSetExtremes` ([link](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes)) to change extremes fitting your needs. So just check interval (compare `this.min` and `this.max`) and then set proper extremes (if interval is to big or to small).

Answer (score 0):

HopeFully I have understood your problem properly

For sample I have made new entries for only 10 seconds you just replace that thing with appropriate needed value in the setTimeout function

and to shift the navigator to left just add this to your code

```
 xAxis: {min:0, max:3600000}
```

Check this fiddle [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NZwwb/)